# Action Bar is not visible?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

In my android application,I am having a drawer but in order to get the drawer i have to manually click and drag that drawer. How can i add the symbol to my tool bar? ( **by clicking that i want to handle my drawer** ) Also how can i make that toolbar visible in the all other layouts as well?

Here is my activity_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:context=".drawer">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/grey"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/grey"
        app:menu="@menu/menudrawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is my drawer.java

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class drawer extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawer,R.string.Open,R.string.Close);
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: select File -> new -> activity -> Navigation drawer activity and compare your code for error or use it as new.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this version of action bar drawer toggle

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the question about toolbar, you need to change this:

```
if (getSupportActionBar()!=null){
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

to just this:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and it should work.
About propagating this behavior on the other screens - you either need to:

1. Add the toolbar and drawer everywhere

or

2. Have this as a base layout in base activity
   and inherit from base activity, adding proper layouts on children

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it helping you according to your need :

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.str_drawer_o, R.string.str_drawer_clos)
if (getSupportActionBar()!=null)
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_nav_icon, this.getTheme());
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });

    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```